# jQuery only showing blank text

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I'm currently running into a problem. The problem is that it returns exactly this `' '` when trying to fetch data from 2 classes above the button.

This is how my `app.js` looks like:

```
$('.edit').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var productNamee = event.target.parentNode.childNodes[1].textContent;
    $('#productname').val(productNamee);
    $('#myModal').modal('show'); 
});
```

This is how my code looks like where it's implemented:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Brand</th> 
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Posted On</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach($posts as $post)
    <tr>
        <div class="postcontest">
            <td>{{ $post->productname }}</td>
            <td>{{ $post->brands }}</td> 
            <td>{{ $post->description }}</td>
            <td>{{ $post->created_at }}</td>
        </div> 
        <td>
            <div class="interaction">
                <a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm edit" role="button" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></span></a>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="{{ route('post.delete', ['post_id' => $post->id]) }}" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>                           
    @endforeach
</table>
```

This is what it returns when opening the modal:
https://gyazo.com/b5709533810d4bdb95029db3af8a9c4c (Totally nothing!)

The Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit a product</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="#" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Product Name</label>
                    <input class='form-control' type="text" name="productname" id="productname">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="brands">Brands</label>
                    <input class='form-control' type="text" name="brands" id="brands">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="brands">Cop Link</label>
                    <input class='form-control' type="text" name="coplink" id="coplink">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">    
                    <label for="brands">Description</label>                     
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="description" id="description" rows="5"></textarea>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button></form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Yes, the ID of the text field is `'productname'` and that's all correct.

I'm currently out of ideas on how to fix this, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this line of code return a value? `var productNamee = event.target.parentNode.childNodes[1].textContent;` for example when you put that in console.log(). Also the code of the modal could be useful.

Comment: @LarsMertens Nope, that returns nothing. I added the code of the modal.

Comment: Your modal is fine. Does your code reach the console.log() statement? Or does it stop executing at this line `event.preventDefault();` And is the click function being fired?

Comment: @LarsMertens Yeah it fires off the click function because the modal actually appears when I click on the button. And It gives me this error in the console: https://gyazo.com/933458e3682a7ac975fa8ce8110998e3

Comment: This line of code is incorrect: `event.target.parentNode.childNodes[1].textContent`.

Comment: @LarsMertens Can you provide me with the solution for that line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change this code:**

```
<a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm edit" role="button" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></span></a>
```

**To**

```
<a onClick="edit('{{$post->productname}}',
                 '{{$post->brands}}',
                 '{{$post->description}}', 
                 '{{$post->created_at}}')," 
                 class="btn btn-warning btn-sm edit" role="button" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></span></a>
```

**And**

```
$('.edit').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var productNamee = event.target.parentNode.childNodes[1].textContent;
    $('#productname').val(productNamee);
    $('#myModal').modal('show'); 
});
```

**To**

```
function edit(productname, brands, description, created_at) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#productname').val(productname);
    $('#brands').val(brands);
    $('#description').val(description);
    $('#created_at').val(created_at);
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```

Comment: This returns an error in the console log: https://gyazo.com/400588979db01c0f609c241490b33a9d

Comment: Had to change a few things. I think its fine now.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now! How would I do this for all the fields that need to be entered in the modal tho?

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Let me see if i can clean it up a bit if you want all fields.

Comment: I think something like I updated could help you out. There are plenty of other solutions but this is in the context of the question.

Comment: Indeed, I edited a little bit of it and now it works! Thanks a lot <3

Comment: @JeroenBreevoort – Lars made some important changes to correct problems in your original post, however I _strongly_ suggest avoiding inline `onClick` handlers; attaching event handlers as you originally did is preferable as it is more maintainable and leads to better [Separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns#HTML.2C_CSS.2C_JavaScript) [of](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/09/06/separation-of-concerns-in-web-services.html) [Concerns](https://effectivesoftwaredesign.com/2012/02/05/separation-of-concerns/), a core principle of software development and architecture.

Comment: @StephenP Could you provide me with the code I should use instead of his one?